# Internal Database location of Properties data

Tags: properties, custom-properties

I have a number of documents stored in a Sharepoint library which has a number of properties. The data which I need to store in each property is available in a temporary sql table.

I'm trying to somehow save this data through the use of sql by updating the internal SharePoint library, but I'm having trouble finding where exactly they're stored (table-wise). Failing that, is there a quick and easy way of doing something similar? Doing it manually will take ages, and writing a highly specific program isn't going to be much faster.

Answer (score 3):

You should never attempt to modify stuff in the SP database programatically. Doing so will put your SP into an unsupported state. Make a program or PowerShell script to update the SPList or SPListItem objects via the SharePoint API.